# Creating an empty multidimensional array

Tags: python, numpy

In Python when using `np.empty()`, for example `np.empty((3,1))` we get an array that is of size (3,1) but, in reality, it is not empty and it contains very small values (e.g., `1.7*(10^315)`). Is possible to create an array that is really empty/have no values but have given dimensions/shape?

Comment: How do you define empty?

Comment: I think OP is looking for a variable that has shape but doesn't really have values.

Comment: Yes, what @Sraw said is what I mean by empty.

Comment: A numpy array always has the number of values implied by the shape. If `np.empty` confuses you, I suggest `np.zeros`instead.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using `np.full_like` to choose the fill-value directly...

```
x = np.full_like((3, 1), None, dtype=object)
```

... of course the dtype you chose kind of defines what you mean by *"empty"*

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that by empty, you mean an array filled with zeros.

Use `np.zeros()` to create an array with zeros. `np.empty()` just allocates the array, so the numbers in there are garbage. It is provided as a way to even reduce the cost of setting the values to zero. But it is generally safer to use `np.zeros()`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use `np.nan`. like shown below,

```
yourdata = np.empty((3,1)) * np.nan
```

(Or)

you can use `np.zeros((3,1))`. but it will fill all the values as `zero`. It is not intuitively well. I feel like using `np.nan` is best in practice.

Its all upto you and depends on your requirement.